# What is the time complexity of Map.prototype.keys()?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, data-structures, ecmascript-6, time-complexity

I am trying to calculate the time complexity of this particular line in one of my functions:

```js
return [...cache.keys()].sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

This line is supposed to return a sorted Array of the Map's (`cache`) keys.
I know that `Array.prototype.sort()` has O(n log n) time complexity. What is the time complexity of `Map.prototype.keys()`?

Comment: Does the [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-map.prototype.keys) help?

Comment: Looks like O(n) from the docs. But it wouldn't surprise me if the actual implementation was more efficient.

Comment: @siride You can't get better than `O(n)` to create an array of `n` items.

Comment: @Bergi you can if you don't actually create it but just it alias whatever we internal list of keys already exists. Whether the implementations do that or not, I don't know. But they could.

Comment: @siride `[... …]` *does* actually create an array, not just alias it to some (mutable) internal list. It's also necessary for sorting, as you can't reorder the internal list. And even if this was optimised, it wouldn't matter, since your runtime complexity is indeed dominated by the `O(n log n)` sort.

Comment: @Bergi Fair enough. I'd like to think optimization could be done, but yes, it seems pretty much impossible here. If maps are small, then it's probably not an issue.

Comment: @siride The point of complexity analysis is that it won't be an issue even for large maps :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating the iterator is `O(1)`, iterating all entries and creating an array from them is linear in the size of the collection - `O(n)`.

Depending on the implementation, the number of recently deleted entries might have an impact, but it never should be large enough to change the time complexity to become non-linear.